# l3build - Non-flat directory of tests?

Tags: l3build

For my tests, I use the following flat structure, which is functional.

```
tests
├── showcase-no-stripe-page-break-1.lvt
├── showcase-no-stripe-page-break-2.lvt
├── tdocenv-back-return.lvt
├── tdocenv-spacing-EN.lvt
└── tdocenv-spacing-EN.lvt
```

It seems more practical to me to be able to proceed as follows. I'm thinking of the increasing of the number of tests.

```
tests
├── showcase
│   ├── no-stripe-page-break-1.lvt
│   └── no-stripe-page-break-2.lvt
└── tdocenv
    ├── back-return.lvt
    ├── spacing-EN.lvt
    └── spacing-FR.lvt
```

It doesn't seem feasible to me, but is there a `Lua` way to get the tests functional with the second organization of tests.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to split your tests into different configurations, each of which then has a directory containing the tests: `l3build` expects each test directory to be 'flat'.

Comment: Is there some examples somewhere?

Comment: @projetmbc Any of the setups with more than one config: the LaTeX2e base might be a place to start

Comment: I will study it. Thanks.